# Can't bind UserControl color property to ToggleButton background

Tags: c#, wpf

I don't get it... I made a simple `UserControl` made of a togglebutton to open a popup containing a `CustomControl`, a colorpicker.

No problem to open/close the popup only if I write a color name for the toggle background color.

But, if I try to bind the UserControl Color property, to see the selected color when popup is closed, then the toggle button doesn't appear and is not working at all.

I must be missing a detail somwhere because I thought it was as simple as this :

```
<ToggleButton 
    x:Name="OpenColorPicker"  
    Style="{DynamicResource ToggleColorPickerStyle}" 
    Background="{Binding DataContext.SelectedColor, ElementName=ColorPickerWidget, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    />
```

Unfortunately not..

Here is the full XAML file :

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
mc:Ignorable="d" 
x:Class="CMiX.ColorSelector"  
xmlns:colorPicker="clr-namespace:ColorPicker;assembly=ColorPicker"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CMiX"
Height="Auto" Width="Auto" d:DesignWidth="44.533" d:DesignHeight="24.933"
x:Name="ColorPickerWidget">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BaseDarkColor" Color="#FF323232"/>
    <local:ColorToBrushConverter x:Key="ColorToBrush"/>
    <Style x:Key="ToggleColorPickerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="OpenColorPicker"  Style="{DynamicResource ToggleColorPickerStyle}" Background="{Binding DataContext.SelectedColor, ElementName=ColorPickerWidget, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <Popup x:Name="PopupColorPicker" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" AllowsTransparency="True" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=OpenColorPicker}" StaysOpen="True" Placement="Right">
        <Border Margin="20, 20, 0, 20" Padding="5">
            <colorPicker:ColorPicker x:Name="ColorPicker" Background="{StaticResource BaseDarkColor}" Width="420" Height="210" SelectedColor="{Binding DataContext.SelectedColor, ElementName=ColorPickerWidget, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <colorPicker:ColorPicker.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect  BlurRadius="20" Opacity="1" Direction="0"/>
                </colorPicker:ColorPicker.Effect>
            </colorPicker:ColorPicker>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

The `UserControl` called ColorPickerWidget has this property :

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty
SelectedColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedColor", typeof(Color), typeof(ColorSelector));
public Color SelectedColor
{
    get { return (Color)GetValue(SelectedColorProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedColorProperty, value); }
}
```

Any idea ?

Thank you

EDIT __

I tried this :

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="OpenColorPicker" Background="{Binding SelectedColor, ElementName=ColorPicker, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrush}}"/>
```

With this converter :

```
public class ColorToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    SolidColorBrush _red = new SolidColorBrush(), 
                    _green = new SolidColorBrush(), 
                    _blue = new SolidColorBrush(), 
                    _alpha = new SolidColorBrush(),
                    _all = new SolidColorBrush();

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var color = (Color)value;
        switch ((string)parameter)
        {
            case "r":
                _red.Color = Color.FromRgb(color.R, 0, 0);
                return _red;
            case "g":
                _green.Color = Color.FromRgb(0, color.G, 0);
                return _green;
            case "b":
                _blue.Color = Color.FromRgb(0, 0, color.B);
                return _blue;
            case "a":
                _alpha.Color = Color.FromArgb(color.A,
                128, 128, 128);
                return _alpha;
            case "all":
                _all.Color = Color.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B);
                return _all;

        }
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But same problem, the button background gets not color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your binding to `ToggleButton.Background`. First, you're binding to the ColorPicker's `DataContext.SelectedColor`. The `DataContext` is the viewmodel. It's probably the same `DataContext` as the `ToggleButton` has. So you don't need to go to the ColorPicker to find it. But the ColorPicker isn't binding its `SelectedColor` to a viewmodel property anyway, so that's probably just a misunderstanding. Get rid of `DataContext` in that binding, it just sends the Binding off on a wild goose chase to nowhere.

Then you got the name wrong. You named the colorpicker `"ColorPicker"`, but you told the binding to look for `"ColorPickerWidget"`. And `Mode=TwoWay` is pointless because the `ToggleButton` can't change it's `Background` and send the color back to the color picker. But it's background isn't a color anyway; it's a `Brush`. So that couldn't possibly work.

And because it's expecting a `Brush`, you need a converter to convert color to brush. `Brush` properties in XAML are very disorienting because you can give them stuff like the string `"Green"` or `"#882266aa"`, and they work. But that's because they're associated with a `TypeConverter` behind the scenes that converts those strings to `Brush`. But that doesn't work if you bind a `Color` value to the property. It's not intuitively obvious.

Does this binding work for `ToggleButton.Background`?

```
Background="{Binding SelectedColor, ElementName=ColorPicker, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrush}}"
```

Comment: I understand your answer, but for some reason it doesn't work. I use a converter but no luck. Also if I apply the style contained in the XAML I shown above, then the toggle button is unusable. If I don't, then I can use it but it doesn't have the background color.

Comment: @lecloneur "Unusable" means it's not visible? Hmmm. The easiest way to retemplate a control is to right click on it in the visual "Design" view, and select "Edit Template" | "Edit a Copy" off the context menu. That'll copy the entire default style and template into your xaml, so you can start with something that you know is working. First you'll have to take the Style attribute that you've got off the ToggleButton, so as not to confuse the IDE

Comment: well even if I don't restyle the toggle button, it doesn't get a color for its background. Problem with the converter maybe ?

Comment: @lecloneur Good point. Did you write the converter? If so you can put a breakpoint in its Convert method. Either way, you can add `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` to the binding and see what comes out in the VS Output pane at runtime

Comment: your solution is working, just missed the converter parameter to make it working... my bad. Thank for your help.

Comment: @lecloneur Awesome!